# I used virtualenv and installed django1.9 . But I need to uninstall 1.9 and install 1.7. How to do that. Tell me whether that is possible?

Tags: django

I used `virtualenv` and installed `django1.9` .But I need to uninstall `django1.9` and install `django1.7`.

How to do that?

Tell me whether  that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your `virtualenv`, do the following

```
pip uninstall Django

pip install django==1.7
```